# Not getting progress updates saving Area Description

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm making a Google Tango app using Unity. When saving an area description with `AreaDescription.SaveCurrent()` I should be getting progress updates according to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-howto-area-learning):

> While the save is running, TangoEvent notification callbacks are sent that describe the save progress. You can listen for these callbacks by implementing the ITangoEvent interface and listening to AreaDescriptionSaveProgress events.

However, I never get these progress updates during the save. All I get is an event for "100% done" when the save is finished, but I'm not getting any updates in-between (10% done, 17% done, etc).

I was thinking this might be because Tango does not bother on small saves, but I have the same problem even on saves that take several minutes.

Why am I not getting these updates, and what can I do to start getting them?

Comment: I had the same problem, in my case it was because of the other tasks that were taking a lot of time so I only had events for 0%, 94% and 99%, not enough info to make a progress bar :/

Comment: @pierreBaret could you elaborate? What were the other tasks in your situation?

Comment: In my case it was saving other files, and uploading them to a cloud. But my point is that the events are sent but apparently some are just ignored by the callback. In my case I simply implemented the saving part of this tuto for percentage feedbacks https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-howto-area-learning

Comment: Oh, were you doing those things concurrently while saving the ADF? In my scenario, I save the ADF before I do anything else, and it's just during that process that I expect to get updates.

Comment: Yeah those tasks were being done in the main thread while the ADF was being saved. I logged the percentage to figure out what was going on and I only had up to 3 logs (0, 94, 99), but in most cases I only had the 94 one.